# "print preview failed" while printing small sized pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print Barcode labels using `window.print()` function, but when I tried to print the pages with customised tiny size(2.5cm), it is showing like *print preview failed*. It is working for 4cm and above, but I need 2.5 cm.[print with 3cm size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTDi4.png)

```js
function printDiv() {
  window.print();
}
```

```css
@page {
  margin: 0;
  size: 2.5cm;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print" />
```

I am actually working on next js, but I tried on a simple HTML file to make sure not any other classes or configurations doesn't effect the printing.

Comment: For me it works absolutely fine, maybe pick another browser?

Comment: What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome browser in my Ubuntu 20.04 system

Answer (score 0):

finally this strange issue solved when I switched from browser Chrome to Brave.

Google Chrome 111.0.5563.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks for your support.